# Spark/ScalaIDE - Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-ide

Have created a spark program in Scala IDE. Throwing an error when i try to execute

```
package sidSparkPackage

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object firstSparkProgram {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My First Spark Program")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3))

//rdd.first()

println("Executed Successfully!!!!")    
 }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

**[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYGDK.jpg)**

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image, since images are not hosted at SO

Comment: How do you launch your app ?

Comment: Have you tried compiling by hand, then running (`scalac name.scala`, then `scala name`)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something to do with your Build Configuration. It's hard to tell without further details.

Try to specify your main class in your project build configuration.